# package, class and excecutionals files structure

Tags: java

In my Win7 machine I have added in the CLASSPATH like this:

> CLASSPATH=D:\Dev\Java;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_20\lib\ext\QTJava.zip.

In my directory tree I have created a `D:\Dev\Java\abc` folder and placed a filed called `Address.java` that contained this code:

```
package jme;

public class NewClass {
}
```

Having done that,  I created a project that looks like this:

```
package javaapplication1;
package abc; // << Error

public class JavaApplication1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        abc.Address address; // << Error
        System.out.println("Jaaaa");
    }
}
```

Why the `abc` package, when located in the CLASSPATH, is not recognized?

Comment: First of all, you can't write two `package` statements into one file. And the second thing is, you don't have a class called `Address`. It's `NewClass`. And the next time you create a question, you should consider adding the exactly error message to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use import ...

```
package javaapplication1;
import abc.*; // No error if you have the package in the classpath ...

public class JavaApplication1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Address address; // No need to prefix with abc, since you imported it before ...
        System.out.println("Jaaaa");
    }
}
```

You can't declare double package for a class in Java, and I think that is not what you really want to do ...

To import correctly the classes contained in the abc package make sure to have the abc package and their related classes in your classpath ...

Sorry guys for the horrendous mishap, I am kinda new here, but I'm a quick learner.
The CLASSPATH reads: D:\Dev\Java\abc;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_20\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
[image: CLASSPATH]

Comment: Either you meant `import abc.*;` or `import abc.Address;`.

Comment: import abc.*; Yes, exactly.